# How to write Python 3 dictionary in C# .Net Framework 4.6 WPF App

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm new to C# and the .Net Framework 4.6. I do know Python, and I was wondering how to do something like this Python dictionary in C#:

```py
GameData = {"VP":0, "Hamsters":"yes"};
```

I've already looked into C# dictionaries and arrays, that's not what I'm looking for. I want something that can be retrieved by something like this:

```
GameData["Hamsters"];
// Returns "yes"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to c#. Strong typing is a bitch. You do want a dictionary, but you need to specify the types of the key and value in the key value pairs during the instantiation of said dictionary. In your case, its string, and string.

```
Dictionary<string, string> yourDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

Passing in these types in angle brackets after the type name is called generics in c#.

You can use the keyword 'var' to assume the implied type. Sometimes the implied type cannot be determined, and you must specify a type on the left hand side of the assignment operator. Thats not the case here though.

```
var yourDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

You can also use a block at the end of the constructor to specify attributes or properties about the object.

```
var yourDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
  {"aKey", "aValue"},
  {"anotherKey", "anotherValue"} 
};
```

Now you should be able to access the values with

```
yourDictionary["aKey"];
```

and

```
yourDictionary["anotherKey"];
```

Careful though, because trying to get a key thats not there will throw an exception. Adding a duplicate key will also throw an exception. You can put the get calls in a try catch block

```
try{
  yourDictionary["anotherKey"];
}
catch(Exception ex){
  //do something with the error here
}
```

Comment: also, dictionary has a try get method yourDictionary.TryGetValue("aKey", out string yourValue);